# Change typescript config to don't accept 'any'

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, tsx

Is there any way to make the tsConfig to stop accepting the 'any' type.
I have already added `"noImplicitAny": true` but still accepting 'any' as a type.

Comment: "Implicit" means roughly "without saying it out loud". In TypeScript's case, `noImplicitAny` means don't allow situations where the compiler would infer `any` as the type. You're looking for a `noExplicitAny` flag, which does not exist.

Comment: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-explicit-any.md you can use eslint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`"noImplicitAny": true` works for implicit any (so there's an error if a type is inferred as `any`, not when you explicitly write `any` in your code).

There is a check for this in `eslint-typescript` though.

Comment: could you please add to your answer how can we implemented it on eslint by adding `"@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "error"` to `rules`, to choose your answer as the correct answer, just to make the question more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

just add

```
"strict": true
```

to your `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json` file

**OR**

add this lines to your `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json` file

```
"noImplicitAny": true,
"strictFunctionTypes": true,
"strictPropertyInitialization": true,
"noImplicitThis": true,
"alwaysStrict": true,
```